# Generate and serving gz compressed in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gzip

Hi I need to serve from a ASHX a GZ compressed file. In the code I already have the string in clear:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    // this is the code without compression
    HttpRequest Request = context.Request;
    HttpResponse Response = context.Response;

    Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";

    // this is the string to compress and send to the client
    string xml = GenerateXml();

    Response.Write(output);
    Response.End();
}
```

Now and I need to

- compress xml in GZ (for a compressed sitemap file http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php#sitemapXMLExample)
- send it to the Response.OutputStream
- set some HTTP response header (content type, encoding, ecc.)

Any help?

Comment: We are not generating files on demand, but rather on a schedule.  Because our site map contains almost a million URL's this data gets to be quite a lot.  We compress the content when we generate the files, and then store the files on a cdn to be served by the front end when it is requested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could [enable compression](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/d52ff289-94d3-4085-bc4e-24eb4f312e0e.mspx?mfr=true) at IIS level for a specific directory. I believe this will be more efficient than doing it by hand in the generic handler.

---

UPDATE:

You could use [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) to compress the xml directly to thew response stream:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/x-gzip";
    var xml = "<xml/>";
    using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(context.Response.OutputStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
        gzipStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: the client need to received a gz zipped file. I don't want to gzip the HTTP message

Comment: That is not the correct header for this application, that is why you received a gzipped file.
The Content-Type should still be text/xml or application/xml
The Content-Encoding header should be added and set to gzip.

Answer (score 0):

GZip compression is supported in ASP.NET.  A quick Google resulted in these posts which seem to help:

http://west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/10294.aspx - doing GZip
http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/10564.aspx - returning the result

Comment: Near the solution, thanks. I need to serve a application/x-gzip file - not sure on how to proceed